# Object Movement not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've attempted creating 2 games with **Unity** so far -- one is 2D other is 3D. In my 2D game, i haven't had any problems with moving objects.

Here's my code to move my player object to left, on left **UI** button Click:

```
float moveSpeed = 2f;
//.......
//.......
public void SheWalksL()
{
    AniWalkL (); // Animation
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (-moveSpeed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y); // Move Left

}
```

Above code is working on UI `Button` press. But in my **3D game**, when i try to move my `player` object in the same way (with the added 3rd dimension), it's not working. Here's the code:

```
public void ButtonMoveL()
{

    Vector3 movemnt = new Vector3(-2.0f, GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y, 0);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = movemnt * speed; // Move Left(Vantage point: looking down at the scene, along the Y-axis. So, Z is aligned vertically and X is aligned horizontally)

}
```

Only difference is that in the 3D game, i've created the movement vector separately and assigned it to the object velocity, and provided the X value of the vector directly without using a variable. I've also got a "Fire" button, which functions perfectly when pressed, so it can't be a problem with the button event call. Could someone please point out what i've done wrong in the 3D code to make it to not working.

Comment: What is the value of `speed` as this is being run?

Comment: Oh, sorry, speed is 10.
public float speed = 10;

Comment: Use addForce instead of that. It ll be more realistic and it ll fix your problem

Comment: Is used addForce, but still it's not working (?).

GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(movemnt * speed);

Comment: add Debug.log(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity) in your ButtonMoveL and share the result with us. If you get any reasonable reason add your object's inspector screenshot.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks guys for the responses.

This is the Inspector for my player object (google drive link): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-pAZg7R1dMOb0dGNExrQ0Z3MFU/view?usp=sharing

This is the output on my console, when I click the ButtonMoveL button, after I applied the Debug.log(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity); code, as suggested by burak: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-pAZg7R1dMOaExURDgxZzNaNW8/view?usp=sharing

The output (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), obviously says that the player is not moving when i click the button.

(Please help -- i have no idea what's causing this bug)

Comment: @KasunL increase the speed value and check constraints under your Rigidbody component.

Comment: I added your code to my object's FixedUpdate (For physics, not regular Update).
And it worked, so your code is good.